# How can I run a MarkLogic RestAPI call in the context of the query console?

Tags: marklogic

I would like to profile a RestAPI call to a custom function. It seems that I have a couple of options. Please comment on each:

1. Extract the RestAPI call from the access log or request log for a
   given application server port and copy it to the query console. I
   don't know if this is possible, unless I invoke the RestAPI call
   with the `xdmp:http-post` or `xdmp.httpPost` API calls. I'm just not
   sure that profile a Rest call makes sense.
2. I have a custom "zsearch" module/library that handles a search request and compresses
   the result. I think I can add the `return:plan` and `return:metrics`
   option to the parameters for the search query in the `zsearch:get()`
   function, but I don't understand the syntax for doing so in the code
   sample below where I want to hard-code the return calls. Can someone provide an example?

In addition, this module makes use of the search-model-query Rest API call at */MarkLogic/rest-api/models/search-model-query.xqy*. I'm wondering where this module is located because I'd like to review it and add some logging to it. I'm not sure why the code uses the `search-model-query.xqy` library instead of the `search:search` call. It seems that the `search:search` invocation would be more efficient than what appears to be a subsequent Rest API call from within a database module.

I would also like to understand what would be required to port this code from using *search-model-query.xqy* to the `search:search` functionality described in https://docs.marklogic.com/search:search.

Here is the zsearch code:

````
module namespace zsearch = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/zsearch";

import module namespace lid = "http://marklogic.com/util/log-id"
  at "/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/log-id.xqy";

import module namespace searchmodq = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/search-model-query"
  at "/MarkLogic/rest-api/models/search-model-query.xqy";

import module namespace sut = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/lib/search-util"
  at "/MarkLogic/rest-api/lib/search-util.xqy";

import module namespace eput = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/lib/endpoint-util"
  at "/MarkLogic/rest-api/lib/endpoint-util.xqy";

declare default function namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions";

declare option xdmp:mapping "false";
(:
declare option xdmp:transaction-mode "auto";
:)

declare private function zsearch:response-callback(
  $response-type as xs:string?
) as empty-sequence()
{
 eput:response-type-callback($response-type),

 let $timestamp := xdmp:request-timestamp()
 return if (exists($timestamp)) then eput:add-response-header("ML-Effective-Timestamp",string($timestamp)) else ()
 
};

declare private function zsearch:query-parameter(
  $paramMap   as map:map,
  $params     as map:map,
  $name       as xs:string,
  $required   as xs:boolean,
  $repeatable as xs:boolean,
  $allowed    as xs:string*,
  $privileges as xs:string*,
  $converter  as function(*)?
) as map:map
{
  let $values := map:get($params,$name)
  return (
      if (not($required) or exists($values[. ne ""])) then ()
      else error((),"REST-REQUIREDPARAM",$name),

      if (empty($values))
      then $paramMap
      else (
          if (empty($privileges) or xdmp:has-privilege($privileges, "execute")) then ()
          else error((),"REST-INVALIDPARAM", concat(
              $name," parameter requires at least one privilege: ",string-join($privileges,", ")
              )),

          if ($repeatable or count($values) lt 2) then ()
          else error((),"REST-REPEATEDPARAM",$name),

          map:with($paramMap,$name,
              if (empty($allowed) and empty($converter))
              then $values
              else
                  let $fname  :=
                      if (empty($converter)) then ()
                      else function-name($converter)
                  let $fns    :=
                      if (empty($fname)) then ()
                      else namespace-uri-from-QName($fname)
                  let $flocal :=
                      if (not($fns = ("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"))) then ()
                      else local-name-from-QName($fname)
                  for $val in $values
                  let $converted :=
                      if (empty($converter))
                      then $val
                      else if (empty($flocal) or xdmp:castable-as($fns,$flocal,$val))
                      then $converter($val)
                      else error((),"REST-INVALIDPARAM", concat(
                          $name, " parameter not convertible to xs:",
                          local-name-from-QName($fname)," value: ",string($val)
                          ))
                  return
                      if (exists($allowed) and not($converted = $allowed))
                      then error((),"REST-INVALIDTYPE",
                          ($name, $val, "is not one of", string-join($allowed, "|")))
                      else $converted
              )
          )
      )
};

declare private function zsearch:validate-parameter-names(
  $paramMap        as map:map,
  $params          as map:map,
  $ignore-patterns as xs:string*
) as xs:string*
{
  for $name in map:keys($params)
  return
      if (map:contains($paramMap,$name)) then ()
      else zsearch:check-ignore($name,$ignore-patterns)
};

declare private function zsearch:check-ignore(
  $name            as xs:string,
  $ignore-patterns as xs:string*
) as xs:string?
{
  if (exists($ignore-patterns) and exists(
      for $pattern in $ignore-patterns
      return
          if (matches($name,$pattern))
          then true()
          else ()
      ))
  then ()
  else $name
};

declare private function zsearch:compress(
  $data            as document-node()*
) as document-node()
{
  let $zip := xdmp:zip-create(
      <parts xmlns="xdmp:zip"><part>result.json</part></parts>,
      ($data)
  )
  return document { $zip }
};

declare function zsearch:get($context as map:map, $params as map:map) as document-node()* {

  let $headers   := eput:get-request-headers()
  let $accept    := eput:get-accept-types($headers)
  let $method    := eput:get-request-method($headers)
  let $env       := eput:response-callback-map(zsearch:response-callback#1)
  let $paramMap  := map:new()
      =>zsearch:query-parameter($params,"q",false(),false(),(),(),())
      =>zsearch:query-parameter($params,"category",false(),true(),("content","metadata","collections","permissions","properties","quality","metadata-values"),(),())
      =>zsearch:query-parameter($params,"format",false(),false(),("json","xml"),(),())
      =>zsearch:query-parameter($params,"start",false(),false(),(),(),xs:unsignedLong#1)
      =>zsearch:query-parameter($params,"pageLength",false(),false(),(),(),xs:unsignedLong#1)
      =>zsearch:query-parameter($params,"options",false(),false(),(),(),())
      =>zsearch:query-parameter($params,"collection",false(),true(),(),(),())
      =>zsearch:query-parameter($params,"directory",false(),false(),(),(),())
      =>zsearch:query-parameter($params,"view",false(),true(),("none","results","metadata","facets","all"),(),())
      =>zsearch:query-parameter($params,"txid",false(),false(),(),(),())
      =>zsearch:query-parameter($params,"database",false(),false(),(),(),())
      =>zsearch:query-parameter($params,"forest-name",false(),true(),(),(),())
      =>zsearch:query-parameter($params,"transform",false(),false(),(),(),())
      =>zsearch:query-parameter($params,"timestamp",false(),false(),(),(),())
      =>zsearch:query-parameter($params,"trace",false(),true(),(),"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/rest-tracer",())
  let $extra-names := zsearch:validate-parameter-names(
      if ($method = ("GET", "HEAD"))
          then zsearch:query-parameter($paramMap,$params,"structuredQuery",false(),false(),(),(),())
          else $paramMap,
      $params,
      ('name')
      )
  return (
      if (empty($extra-names)) then ()
      else error((),"REST-UNSUPPORTEDPARAM", concat(
          "invalid parameters: ",string-join($extra-names,", ")
          )),

      lid:enable(map:get($paramMap,"trace")),

      if (searchmodq:check-untraced()) then ()
      else lid:log(
          $searchmodq:trace-id,"zearch",
          map:entry("method",$method)=> map:with("headers",$headers)=> map:with("parameters",$paramMap)
          ),

      if (empty($accept)) then ()
      else if ($accept = ("application/json", "text/json", "application/xml", "text/xml")) then
          if (map:contains($paramMap,"category"))
          then error((),"REST-UNSUPPORTEDPARAM",
              "Can use the 'category' parameter only with multipart/mixed accept")
          else
              let $view := map:get($paramMap,"view")
              return
                  if (not($view eq "none")) then ()
                  else error((),"REST-UNSUPPORTEDPARAM",
                      "Can use the 'none' value for the 'view' parameter only with multipart/mixed accept")
      else if (starts-with(head($accept),"multipart/mixed"))
      then map:put($env,"add-header",eput:add-response-header#2)
      else error((), "REST-UNACCEPTABLETYPE", string-join($accept,", ")),

      let $_ := 1
      return (
          let $response :=  searchmodq:search-get($headers,$paramMap,$env)
          let $has-matches := map:get($env, "has-matches")
          return
              if (exists($response)) then 
(:
                  let $_ := map:put($context,"output-type","application/octet-stream") 
:)
                  let $_ := xdmp:set-response-content-type("application/octet-stream")
                  return zsearch:compress($response)
              else if ($has-matches) then ()
              else xdmp:set-response-code(404,"Not Found")
      )
  )
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`xdmp:http-get()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:http-get) or `xdmp:http-post()` to hit the actual endpoint and invoke it via HTTP with the appropriate action. And you can specify the [`return-plan`](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_71285) and [`return-metrics`](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_68566) in the options:

```
xdmp:http-get("http://localhost:8000/LATEST/config/resources/zsearch",
  <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
    <authentication method="basic">
      <username>myname</username>
      <password>mypassword</password>
      <return-metrics>true</return-metrics>
      <return-plan>true</return-plan>
    </authentication>
  </options>)
```

You could also import the installed REST module and invoke it's methods programmatically instead of through the HTTP endpoint:

```
   import module namespace zsearch = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/zsearch" 
     at "/marklogic.rest.resource/zsearch/assets/resource.xqy";
   let $context as map:map := map:new()
   let $params as map:map := map:new()
   return
     zsearch:get($context, $params)
```

You could also use [`xdmp:plan()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:plan) and [`xdmp:query-meters()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:query-meters)

The module `/MarkLogic/rest-api/models/search-model-query.xqy` can be found in the MarkLogic install for any MarkLogic server. It lives under the installed location at `/Modules/MarkLogic/rest-api/models/search-model-query.xqy`.

Comment: Much appreciated Mads - this sounds like a simple way forward.

Comment: Hi Mads, et al,

1. My zsearch http get request:

"http://server:8111/v1/resources/zsearch?rs:format=json&rs:options=all&rs:pageLength=..."

Running the xdmp:http-get returns an invalid entity reference messages:

XDMP-ENTITYREF: (err:XPST0003) Invalid entity reference "rs:"

I tried to declare a namespace, 

  declare namespace rs = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search";

but still got the same error. At least I think that is the correct namespace to use...

2. For the programmatic approach, I don't know how to create the context and parameters. Any recommendations?

Tim

Comment: The $context you likely don't need to worry about, but is where you can set properties controlling response format, headers, etc. https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_81113 As for the parameter map, use either `map:with()` or `map:put()` to create the input parameters. So, if you had querystring parameter `rs:foo=bar`, `map:put($params, "foo", "bar")`

Comment: While I can attempt to profile the query, my suspicion is that combing a search query with a structured query is not working as expected. That's a bold statement to make without being able to characterize the problem in the search API libraries. I think that one of two things is happening, that the ANDing of the two queries coming with ANDing with the structured query is not properly nested, or that the sequence/order of queries is problematic. Filtering by end date alone yields over 12 million documents to search in - it's adding the end date where the extended search delay occurs.

Comment: If I simply apply the string query without a structured query start or end date, the request completes very quickly. It also completes using a start date range index query (GE) because the number of documents is fairly small compared to using just an end date (LE) query.

So it seems that the unfiltered date range query is presenting 12+ millions documents for the search string query and that it is slowing down the works.

Maybe the question to ask is, why and when does combining a structured query that uses date range-based indexing along with a search string query present delays?

Comment: well, it's good to be able to boil it down and isolate to a simple search case. That might make it easier to analyze and troubleshoot. Is it consistently slow with subsequent queries or just the first time? You could try applying the `cached-incremental` option to see if that helps any. Check the Usage Notes for explanation of the option: https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-range-query

Comment: It does make me wonder about caching sizes and options. It could very well be that this is the crux of the problem. Can you also make recommendations about what caches I might try to increase the memory allocation for and how to go about doing that? It just might be the silver bullet.